# Best way to manage several DB Columns and 1 widget in Django

Tags: django, widget

I have a models with several db fields (field1, field2)
I want to create an unique widget to fill value for field1,field2

Possible solution ?

- set my widget on field1, and set HiddenInput for field2. But I don't like so much this solution. Is that correct solution at least ?

Is there some other solutions ? like create 1 FormField that is mapped to 2 DB Fields (Not easy to do that in Django Admin)

I checked several solution for similar needs LatLonField, but in the examples I found, lat and lot are stored in a commaseparatedfield which is not acceptable for me.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a [`MultiValueField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#multivaluefield)

Comment: Not sure it's what I want. MultiValueField is a form Field (not db Field). For my understanding, MultipleValueField can render several widget and save all in a DB field.

What a want is 1 widget and save in 4 db columns. In order words, Is there a way to create a DB field with several db columns ?

Comment: Finally I found this:
https://gist.github.com/gipi/2401143
and
http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2008/01/08/fuzzydates-or-one-django-model-field-multiple-database-columns/